# Some (random) textures rendering upside down in OpenGL?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es-2.0, textures, glkit

I'm using GLKit (OpenGL ES2) in Objective-C to make an iPhone game.

I haven't had a lot of experience with this, so it wouldn't surprise me if I was doing something wrong, but I am generating a heap of objects, which are all mostly the same. In fact I am using a class for them, and just making more instances of the class to create more objects, but somehow some of the objects have textures mapped upside down.

I don't see how this is at all possible since it is the same code used for all of the objects, and some of them are correct, and some aren't.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the images from? Some formats have the origin in the upper left, some in the lower left. It just depends on the image.

Comment: The image is a tif generated from [UIImage imageNamed:].
This can't be the case though, as some of the objects are rendering correctly, and some aren't, so I can't just flip it, as this will affect all of them, and I will still have this problem. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Some formats such as TGA (for example) support both origins format. This means that the simple extension of the images, do not exclude the advice given by  user1118321.

Comment: The file format is tif. does this do the same thing? If so, why does it only happen to some, and not all, and how can this be fixed? Cheers

Comment: I don't see how this is possible either, since I **don't see anything**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by not re-using the texture over and over again, but regenerating it each time I needed it.

All in all, it's much better practice to only generate the texture once and reuse it anyway, so the solution is simply to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `[UIImage imageOrientation]` property to see if the image is flipped. It could be [one of these values](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
UIImageOrientationUp
UIImageOrientationDown
UIImageOrientationLeft
UIImageOrientationRight
UIImageOrientationUpMirrored
UIImageOrientationDownMirrored
UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored
UIImageOrientationRightMirrored
```

Comment: I put a log in, and it's returning 0 for all of them (Up, I assume). But not all of them are up the right way...
Thanks for your help, but this mustn't be it either..

Comment: Are all your quads defined in the same winding order (clockwise vs. counterclockwise)? And are all of the faces of the quads that are facing the camera front faces?

Comment: Yeah, the same coordinates are used for all of them, so they are all oriented the same way.

Comment: What do you mean "the same coordinates are used for all of them?" If that were the case, you'd only ever see 1 of them. Or are you doing some sort of cross dissolve between them?

Comment: The same coordinates are used to make the object, then I change the transform matrices to move them

Comment: OK, that means they have the same winding order, but it doesn't guarantee that their front faces are all facing the camera, though. Since you haven't said what those transformations are, it could be the case that they're all facing the same way, but I can't tell from your description. That's why I put it out there. Beyond that, I'm not sure what else the problem could be off the top of my head.

Comment: All the transform does is move it along the x/y axis. No rotation is involved.